# wolfram interprets test for equality as equality

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

input1: m*x''[t] + k*x[t] + b*x'[t] == 0

output1: m*x''[t] + k*x[t] + b*x'[t] == 0

input2: x‘[0]==0

output2: True

I want output to be x‘[0]==0
How can I fix?

Comment: Mathematica remembers everything during a session in a cache. If in a fresh new notebook, with an empty cache,  I enter `mx''[t] + k*x[t] + b*x'[t] == 0` then it responds with `mx''[t] + k*x[t] + b*x'[t] == 0` and if I enter `x'[0]==0` then it responds with `x'[0]==0` so I am GUESSING that you probably previously entered `x'[0]=0` and that stored that value for `x'[0]` and that was why it responded to your later `x'[0]==0` with `True` IF you wanted to take that out of the cache then you could enter `x'[0]=.` and that would remove that from the cache. Try all this and make certain that it works